# Create a Maintenance plan to update user account status

Tags: sql, sql-server, maintenance-plan

I am looking to create a maintenance plan in the SQL Server Management Studio. For this maintenance plan, I need to update user accounts to a status = 0 (deactivated) after checking if the user has left the company or not.

I have already gone ahead and walked through the Maintenance plan wizard

```
-- Script to inactivate all users even if they are active
UPDATE USERS SET ACCOUNTSTATUS= 0 WHERE ACCOUNTSTATUS = 1
```

I know this is just the beginning of it, I need to create a SQL statement which will allow me to check a certain table and find if the user is not active. If they are not active, the maintenance plan will run and deactivate their account from the application.

UPDATE: The requirement for this is to also implement an Email to be sent out with the list of users that were deactivated. In order to this, I need to either create a Job that can ultimately be the same as using the Maintenance plan. What are the next steps after this? Here is the TRIGGER UPDATE which I plan to use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateUser on dbo.USERS
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE dbo.USERS
    SET ACCOUNTSTATUS = em.ACCOUNTSTATUS
    FROM dbo.USERDETAILS AS ud ()    
    INNER JOIN Inserted AS em
    on ud.ACCOUNTSTATUS = em.ACCOUNTSTATUS
END
GO
```

Comment: why not simply schedule a sql job to run this code periodically and update? Alternatively, you can set a trigger on source table where accountstatus is held, and trigger an update?

Comment: This is my initial plan, knowing that they both will do the same thing, How do I create an appropriate statement which triggers the update to accountstatus, if the accountstatus = 0?

Comment: it won't do anything if accountstatus = 0. You explicitly specify in your where clause the accountstatus = 1.. so for any records where it is 0.. it simply won't do anything. Unless you want something else to happen if accountstatus = 0!

Comment: You don't need a maintenance plan. A maintenance plan is for maintenance to your DB (backups, integrity checks, etc). This is simply an update statement. You have an XY Problem.